# MariaDB Galera setup with drastically different amounts of memory used on cluster nodes - why?

Tags: mysql, innodb, memory, mariadb, galera

We have a 3 node MariaDB Galera cluster.

All nodes are identical and the config on each is identical. They have 64GB of RAM each.

The output of the following query is `28`:

```
SELECT CEILING(Total_InnoDB_Bytes*1.6/POWER(1024,3)) RIBPS FROM
(SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) Total_InnoDB_Bytes
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB') A;
```

Our database is growing quite quickly and the machines are dedicated so `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is now set to `56G`. Originally it was set to `256M`, we just increased it this morning (the cluster was only set up a couple of days ago).

My question is why is the amount of RAM used on each machine so drasticly different, see the graph below. When we changed `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to `56G` (and did a rolling-restart) they all jumped up by around the same amount (in real terms, not proportionally), but as you can see are clearly still quite different. Can anybody shed some light on why?

Thanks!

[image: Physical Memory Used in DB Machines]

Comment: I don't have enough rep yet to create tags, but wouldn't `galera` be a suitable tag for this site? I'm surprised it's not already there.

Comment: One of the team has suggested that given the servers have only been running a couple of days, we might expect them to converge over the next week or two? Maybe Dalmatian did more intensive queries on average than the other two? Would that seem sensible? @Colin 't Hart thanks for the tag.

Comment: Just in case anyone is looking at this, I can confirm that over time they all converged and now run with the same memory usage +/- a couple of percentage points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InnoDB buffer pool caches queries; if you have less usage on one of the nodes then you're going to have less cache used.

If you're not properly load-balancing queries then the amount of cache in use on each node would be different. If you just turned on a node and added it to the cluster the amount of cache would be different than the others one that have been long running.

It doesn't matter if you use Galera in this case as this is a specific InnoDB question; sure you could be using Galera, but it has nothing to do with this caching question you've asked.

Comment: Individual page loads/cli scripts are load balanced, but when the cluster had not been running for long some major cli scripts had happened to hit the same server repeatably. Over the time since then we they have all come in line. Thanks for your explanation though.